# How to write inline latex code in IPython notebook

Tags: python, latex, ipython

This might be painfully obvious but how do I write Latex script inline in IPython notebook file so when it is parsed it does not start a new line?

Comment: sorry, ignore that. It is obvious. Single $ rather than $$.

Comment: Go ahead and answer your own question!

Answer (score 14):

The answer can be found in this helpful [cookbook](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/cookbook.html)

Inline uses `$...$`

Displayed used `$$...$$`